# Is there anyway to find out if the appended tag gets 404 error or not by using Java Script or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I'm working on Spring MVC Web project with JSP.
I made a function that users attach an image, and add image tag to a certain area.

but it requires 3 to 5 seconds for image to be uploaded on Server, so the appended image tag doesn't get 404 error.

I'm thinking to repeat adding the image tag till the image to be uploaded on server.

Is there anyway to find out if the tag gets 404 error by using Java Script or jQuery?

Any help towards finding a solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about `<img src="?" onerror='callback(event)' onload='callback(evetn)'/>` ?

Comment: OMG, that's simple and easy, but can be a remarkable solution..... Thnx.... then do you think I can limit user not able to do anything while they wait for image to be uploaded?

Comment: Give the user a message that if they leave the page the upload will be broken, and use a nice loading gif from http://loading.io/ or http://www.ajaxload.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, what I used was onerror attributes.

FYI, the 3~5 seconds was not required when I run the project on Tomcat 7.0 server.

I guess it only took the delay time when I run it on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example,I hope it will help you.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "...",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (returnMsg) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("error code is:" + err.status);
            }
        });
```

If an error occurs,the err.status's value may be 404,400 and so on.